# Recover Android SharedPreferences string

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences to save a JSON string between sessions. A bug in my app made me overwrite the string with the empty String.

Is there any way I can recover the string that was previously saved? Assume full access to the phone (ADB / root)

Comment: Looks like *no* to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, **there is no way to recover that**, as you replaced it with blank.
It can contain only one value at a time.

Comment: And no automatic backups or ways to find the data on the device even though its deleted?